# Firefox Div gap issue

Tags: css, firefox, layout

I have an annoying problem, it works fine in chrome but in firefox there is a gap for no reason between two divs.

```
<div class="body-right">     
  <!-- VERTICAL GAP IS HERE -->
  <div class="body-right-container">
  <div class="body-right-pad"> 
</div>
</div>
```

Chrome: http://gyazo.com/d5464f5fe791c3958d28816dfd03803c

Firefox: http://gyazo.com/f5f25eeab19622a2696e2d2510e1ea07

Nothing in my css has any kind of margin that would be causing this gap. Any ideas?

```
.body-right {
    float: left;
    width: 767px;       
    background-color:#ebebeb;
    border-left: #c7c7c7 1px solid;
    padding-left: 1px;
    min-height: inherit;
}

.body-right-container {
display:block;
    background-color:#ebebeb;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 49px 49px;
    min-height: inherit;
}

.body-right-pad {
    width: 300%;
    background-color:#ebebeb;
    position: absolute;
    left: 765px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code as part of your question. (this includes your CSS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a large gray rectangle on the far right, that element could be potentially the one that's creating your "gap". I see it on the Firefox screenshot, but not in the Chrome.

You should investigate that element and see why it's appearing there in Firefox. This could possibly be due to a `width:100%` applied to the container holding that gray rectangle.

Comment: that was the background elementm anyway I solved it apparently one of the elements within was too big causing some weird layout problems.

Comment: @Jedigasm Ah, ok. Glad you solved it, though next time it's a lot easier for everyone to help you with your question if you include as much detail as possible, perhaps a [page](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem :)

Comment: @Jedigasm If you are not able to share more info, please consider removing this question. As it stands (due to the lack of information) it's not particularly informative to future viewers, and since it is "unanswered," it will keep appearing on the homepage.

Comment: how do  Iclose the question.